# set value of a column equal to value of another column where date is one week ago in same table

Tags: mysql

I want to update a column in table with value depending another column value in the same table. For example I have company_table as below

```
fldId | companyName |    date     | fldState
---------------------------------------------
  1   | adeco       | 2023-06-18  |  
  2   | mic         | 2023-06-17  |
  3   | manpower    | 2023-06-16  |
  4   | linar       | 2023-06-15  |
  5   | dlank       | 2023-06-14  |
  5   | test        | 2023-06-13  |
  5   | tesla       | 2023-06-12  |
  5   | apple       | 2023-06-11  |
```

I want to update 'fldState' column in this table depending on value of 'date' column. For example if value of 'date' column is '2023-06-18' then value of 'fldState' should be 'tesla' (value of one week ago)

```
fldId | companyName |    date     | fldState
---------------------------------------------
  1   | adeco       | 2023-06-18  |  tesla
  2   | mic         | 2023-06-17  |  apple
  3   | manpower    | 2023-06-16  |  ...
  4   | linar       | 2023-06-15  |
  5   | dlank       | 2023-06-14  |
  5   | test        | 2023-06-13  |
  5   | tesla       | 2023-06-12  |
  5   | apple       | 2023-06-11  |
```

Comment: `update mysterytablename a join mysterytablename b on b.date=a.date - interval 7 day set a.fldState=b.companyName`   but you are better off not storing this redundant data, just joining in a select when you need it.

Comment: what is mysterytablename ?

Comment: replace it with your table name, which you chose to not show us